# How to remove ?___from_store=fr on the url?

Tags: magento2.2.2

I'm using Magento 2.2.2, I have others language store in my Magento.

how to remove `?___from_store=fr` on the url?

```
http://exsample.com/en/?___from_store=fr
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `Add Store code to URLs` to `yes` in:

> Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> URL Options

**EDIT**

Seems like this is a small Magento 2.2.2. bug.

I don't think that when you have `Add Store code to URLs` set to `yes`, that the `___from_store` should show when changing.

I don't know how to fix it though, but you can check these files to try and figure it out:

> /vendor/magento/module-store/Block/Switcher.php

and

> /vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Controller/Router.php

Comment: They're looking to remove, not add. Maybe the setting should be `no` - not `yes`

Comment: `yes` on that option removes `?__from_store=fr` and changes it to just the store code `fr`

Comment: i already setting `YES`, and i only want store code `en` so how to remove `?___from_store=`, thank you

Comment: Do you also have Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web server Rewrites = Yes?

Comment: @rigu - I don't believe you can strip that part out of the link being shown. It's an on/off feature.

Comment: yes........ how can i hide ?__from_store= @Lez

Comment: this is only show it on index.php? can not hide it? @StevenJ

Comment: my issue is http://exsample.com/fr/ change to http://exsample.com/en/ ... Not http://exsample.com/en/?___from_store=fr.. how can delete ?___from_store= on url , thank you @Lez

Comment: my issue is http://exsample.com/fr/ change to http://exsample.com/en/ ... Not http://exsample.com/en/?___from_store=fr.. how can delete ?___from_store= on url , thank you @StevenJ

Comment: @rigu, check my edit. Hope it helps...

Comment: but i dont know how to fix too....@Lez